# How to package a ruby gui app?

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to make my Qt Ruby application into an executable and distribute on windows? I have seen rubyscript2exe but it looks abandoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ocra](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/) is the successor of rubyscript2exe.